# selectors equivalent for Python 2?

Tags: python, networking, standard-library

Python 3 has the `selectors` module, which allows us to `register` on a file descriptor event, and only later in a different part of the code `select` on it.

In Python 2 we only have the `select` module, which requires that we 'register' and 'select' on the same line, which is limiting.

If I want to register on an event in one function and wait for it ('select') in a different one, how can this be done in Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's two libraries that fill this role: [selectors2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selectors2/1.0) and [selectors34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selectors34).
They're very similar, support Python 2.6+ and are drop-in replacements for the selectors module.  However, selectors2 integrates [PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) which retries system calls when they are interrupted and has a [more robust battery of tests](https://github.com/SethMichaelLarson/selectors2) as well as 100% test coverage and automated testing on all major OSes (Windows, Mac OS, and Linux).

Install the module with:

`python -m pip install selectors2`

The following code will work in Python 2.6+

```
try:
    import selectors
except ImportError:
    import selectors2 as selectors
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of selectors2.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out! :)

Comment: @AvivCohn If you have any issues feel free raise them on Github :) I reply very quickly to mentions.